# paging using jquery four button navigation based on the tr elements classname

Tags: jquery, pagination, datatables, tablesorter

I have a html table like so. To summarize here is what i want. I plan on using tablesorrter plugin for paging, however instead of paging based on all tr rows, i need to only page based on certain tr rows with the same class name. Is it possible to do that.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<table>
  <thead>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
        <tr>     -- 'class' page
         </tr>
          <tr>
          </tr>
        <tr>-- 'class' page
         </tr>
          <tr>
          </tr>
           <tr>-- 'class' page
           </tr>
           <tr>
           </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: -Why- do you have a table like so?

Comment: hey mike.... imagine inside each tobdy the first row is shown while the other siblings are hidden

Comment: Hey Mike I modified the table... is this now doaable?

Comment: @HaranMurthy Does the data come from the server or is it static? If it is static, i don't think you can do it. If it is coming from the server you could use ajax to grab next set of records until they contain that class or something similar.

Comment: Hey Iro. are you suggesting  server side paging?? I do retrieve the data from the table and build the html table dynamically. So this html table ends up with 15000 rows always. but Say only 300 have a certain class name like "Hello" paging should be based on only these 300 and not the entire 15000

Comment: @HaranMurthy Serverside paging is exactly what i'm suggesting. It would be much faster if you are pulling many rows so you would have multiple benefits, besides the pagination. Depends on the language, but if you do server side it would be easier than trying to figure this out in JS.

Comment: @Iro- thanks for your suggestion. I did find a way for paging the static html table. I implemented this for my code and got it to work.  http://www.pengoworks.com/workshop/jquery/tablesorter/tablesorter.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following link helped me solve my riddle.
http://www.pengoworks.com/workshop/jquery/tablesorter/tablesorter.htm

I use the tr rows with no class in them as hidden rows, and this modification helps me collapse and expand. I got it working on a static table and am about to implement into my application. To summarize: Used table sorter to get my paging based on visible row.